# Moment of Inertia in non-rotational context

Tags: rotational-dynamics, elasticity, moment-of-inertia

I have read that Civil Engineers use moment of inertia to characterize the elastic properties (rigidity) of such structures as loaded beams. My doubt is how is Moment of Inertia helpful in explaining the rigidity of the body, Do they measure the $r$ for each $dm$ and check if it doesn't change with time?

Comment: I assume they use the area moment of inertia just like other engineers.

Comment: What is area moment of inertia? Will you please explain it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moment of Inertia of thin lamina is used having same cross section as the object of interest, like for a cylindrical rod, MOI of the corresponding circle is taken. It isn't the mass moment of inertia that is used, rather it is the area moment of inertia which is mass MOI divided by the density, i.e. instead of $r^2dm$ we have $r^2dA$.

Now to understand how it helps determine strength. If you twist a rod, then we imagine it being chopped up into many thin cross sections, each of which rotates w.r.t the one behind it by some angle say $dθ$. Now at any point on this, the shear stress developed is proportional to the relative strain between two adjacent elements, so for an angular displacement dθ the strain at distance r it will be $rdθ/dz$ ($dz$ is length of element in axial direction). So, the shear stress at this element is $s$=$Grdθ/dz$ where G is shear modulus, giving a net force of $sdA$ at the element. Now to determine the total moment (or torque) on the cross section we need a integral over Fr = $rsdA$ = $G(dθ/dz)(r^2)dA$, with G and $dθ/dz$ constant throughout the surface, we are left with the integral of $r^2dA$ which is how area MOI comes into picture.

So, we apply some moment, we measure the rate of angular displacement $dθ/dz$, which is a constant for the whole length due to symmetry and hence is equal to $θ/L$, and with known MOI, we can get the modulus G of the material.

Similar arguments run for bending beam phenomenon, where MOI about some other relevant axis comes into picture and instead of G we have modulus of elasticity E there.